# regarding a graduate program research methods course

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, ethics

To whom it may concern,

I am a graduate student in my didactic year of physician assistant school, and am currently taking our research methods course.  Normally our course was spent the way most research methods courses are- developing a research question, conducting the research and writing the results, with no publication.

However, this semester, we have a new program director who is absolutely head over heels in love with research and has entirely changed the curriculum to include additional papers, assignments and exams, so we don't have time to conduct an actual experiment.  Instead, they want randomly generated data to represent 'results' to our research question and study.

My question is, is this ethical?  Even though we aren't publishing this or presenting this as genuine data to anyone other than our class, it's my understanding that fabricating data is taboo and is a clear violation of everything research stands for.  Insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Using simulated data in a course training students on other aspects of the research process is not unethical. Simulating data is done all the time, for example in testing algorithms or implementations: you often need to start with some known ground-truth so that you can find errors or measure performance.

Representing such data as genuine results is unethical. I would recommend making the data generation process transparent in any written summaries to avoid confusion in the unlikely case the written work is found outside the context of the course.

To be clear, in the situation you describe, you are **not doing research**. You are only learning about some of the steps involved.

Comment: It might actually be more ethical than dealing with some sorts of data involving human subjects. Especially in a medical program.